# Office online with active directory integration

Tags: ms-wopi

How I integrate my WOPI with office online login
[I want to change this with my login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk64d.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the [`SignInUrl`](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html?highlight=url#term-signinurl) and [`SignoutUrl`](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html?highlight=url#term-signouturl) properties of the [`CheckFileInfo`](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html).